# tf.where() doesn't produce result same as np.where()

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm comparing tensorflow to numpy using same logical code.

When implementing tf.where, I can't get the same result as np.where 
What is the problem of the code or usage below?

data :

```
X_batch = np.concatenate([np.arange(10).reshape(1, -1) for i in range(10)], axis=0)
```

tensorflow tf.where toy code :

```
X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[10, 10])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf.where(X > 5, tf.zeros([10, 10], dtype=tf.int32), 
                            X), feed_dict={X: X_batch}))
```

numpy np.where toy code :

```
np.where(X_batch > 5, np.zeros([10,10]), X_batch)
```

​
**Code had some typo errors. correction has done**

Answer (score 0):

I edited the code. Input to tf.where() should be as same as np.where(). Therefore, arguments to the tf.where(), you should give zero 10*10 matrix and x_batch as the inputs as your np.where() method arguments.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


X_batch = np.concatenate([np.arange(10).reshape(1, -1) for i in range(10)], axis=0)

#print(X_batch )

X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[10, 10])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf.where(X > 5, tf.fill([10, 10], 0),
                            X), feed_dict={X: X_batch}))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I meant when used same functional codes of tensorflow and numpy, different result came out, so i asked a question. but now i do that the same thing, it works as same.. sorry for disturbing you